# Why do people suicide?

Tags: neuroscience

No, I am not talking about user suicide. I am talking about actual suicide. Isn't the fear of death naturally so big that people couldn't, but how do they? What would be tormenting them so badly that it overcomes the fear of death? Even if they are physically fit teens with a life ahead of them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do people commit suicide?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/why-do-people-commit-suicide)

Comment: You post this... then suicide?